# Conditionally show Tooltip depending on parent Popper component being open

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, tooltip, popper.js

I am trying to understand the best way of conditionally showing a Tooltip, based on if a sibling component `Popper` is open or not. I want to to show it by default on hover of its child the `ButtonBase`. I want the tooltip to *never* be open if the `Popper` is open. The tooltip title is acting as a summary of what's selected in the options list in the Popper when its closed, having it open with the Popper open is not ideal and cluttered. I am new to hooks so trying to understand how I can incorporate a hook to set the tooltipOpen state correctly with the conditional need.

```
export default function TooltipWithPopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([options[1], options[11]]);
  const [pendingValue, setPendingValue] = React.useState([]);
  const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setPendingValue(value);
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setTooltipOpen(false);
  };

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === "toggleInput") {
      return;
    }
    setValue(pendingValue);
    if (anchorEl) {
      anchorEl.focus();
    }
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "github-label" : undefined;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Tooltip title={value.map((i) => i.title).join(", ")}>
          <ButtonBase
            disableRipple
            className={classes.button}
            aria-describedby={id}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            <span>Label</span>
            {value.length}/{options.length}
          </ButtonBase>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
      <Popper
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        placement="bottom-start"
        className={classes.popper}
      >
        <Autocomplete
          open
          onClose={handleClose}
          multiple
          classes={{
            paper: classes.paper,
            option: classes.option,
            popperDisablePortal: classes.popperDisablePortal
          }}
          value={pendingValue}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setPendingValue(newValue);
          }}
          disableCloseOnSelect
          disablePortal
          renderTags={() => null}
          noOptionsText="No labels"
          .....
        />
      </Popper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Here is a demo of the tooltip being applied to the trigger element. How can I set it to only be open depending on another components' state? I've tried adding a `setTooltipOpen(false)` call when the `handleClick` is called when opens the `Popper`.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0wgyh?file=/demo.js:0-6181

Answer (score 0):

You can control the `Tooltip` `open` prop value with your `tooltipOpen` state (implementation is up to you) and provide conditions that if the `Popper` is `open`, then automatically, the `Tooltip` `open` prop value computation will disregard the `tooltipOpen` state and assign `false`.

In my example below, I control the `tooltipOpen` state via `onMouseEnter` && `onMouseLeave` events

```
<Tooltip
  open={open === true ? false : tooltipOpen}
  title={value.map((i) => i.title).join(", ")}
>
  <ButtonBase
    disableRipple
    className={classes.button}
    aria-describedby={id}
    onClick={handleClick}
    onMouseEnter={() => setOpen(true)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setOpen(false)}
  >
    <span>Label</span>
    {value.length}/{options.length}
  </ButtonBase>
</Tooltip>
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]